# WP - Errors after update from 4.6 LTS to 4.7

Tags: wordpress, upgrade, 4.7, 4.6

Upgrading seems to work fine, I checked folders and resources configuration because the paths weren't there anymore.
Then when I try to access the extensions menu I get the following error :

```
Cannot read unrecognized property CRM_Core_Config::$defaultSymbol.
```

And the extensions list isn't being displayed. I tried turning debugging on but nothing shows

Answer (score 1):

This is highly due to one of the custom extension enabled on your site. Few steps you could try to fix this -

- Check if any of the extension overrides the file `CRM/Core/Config.php`. If you find it, move it outside the site dir and disable that extension after reloading the page.
- Manually disable the extension from the database one by one and try to reload the page. To disable the ext, set `is_active` value to 0 in `civicrm_extension` table. (Remember to revert it back if the page reload is still an error).
- Check if the custom php directory overrides the core file CRM/Core/Config.php. If yes, do the same as step 1.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I searched for another Config.php in the whole project but didn't find anything. I deactivated all extensions in the db like you said, but it did not changed the error. Actually this errors shows up on the dashboard page also... The debugging shows : CRM_Core_Exception: Cannot read unrecognized property CRM_Core_Config::$defaultSymbol. in /web/pui/wp-content/plugins/files/civicrm/templates_c/fr_FR/%%24/24E/24E27851%%jsortable.tpl.php on line 152

Comment: Delete everything inside `/web/pui/wp-content/plugins/files/civicrm/templates_c` - they are only cache files.

Comment: Agree with Christian - also try to rebuild the menu by appending this to the base URL - `civicrm/menu/rebuild?reset=1`